# wpautop - disable <br> tags, keep <p> tags

Tags: functions, editor

I write My articles in Emacs and they end up having tons of newlines, with double newlines to separate paragraphs. Ideally, I want wordpress to work like markup does, meaning it ignores single line breaks but adds paragraphs when a double newline is met.

Unfortunately, disabling wpautop makes Wordpress ignore both single and double newlines. I want to be able to use the function in a way that ignores `<br>` tags for single lines but adds `<p>` tags when two newlines are met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wpautop can ignore the linkebreaks if you use wpautop( $content, false ); To pass a parameter to wpautop via add_filter, use an anonymous function.

This snippets seems to work for me if I add it to my theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
$br = false;
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) use ( $br ) { 
    return wpautop( $content, $br ); 
}, 10 );
```